# EHCache loadAndCorrectConfiguration NPE

Tags: hibernate, spring, ehcache

I try to use ehcache with hibernate/spring. My attempt is throwing a NPE.

I am stuck on this hard. And, Googling is no help.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.HibernateUtil.loadAndCorrectConfiguration(HibernateUtil.java:48)
 at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:79)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:236)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
 ... 99 more
```

Here is my spring configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.agriserver.domain.AaFriend</value>
        </list>
    </property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

        <!-- Enable EHCache -->
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Here is the ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <cache
            name="com.agriserver.domain.AaFriend"
            maxElementsInMemory="10"
            maxElementsOnDisk="1000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="300"
            timeToLiveSeconds="600"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            />

    <cache
            name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="1"
            eternal="false"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="false"/>
</ehcache>
```

Excerpt from pom.xml to show the versions of jar files:

```
<properties>
    <cxf.version>2.2.7</cxf.version>
    <spring.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.annotations.version>3.3.0.ga</hibernate.annotations.version>
    <facebook.version>3.0.2</facebook.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                <!--<version>2.03</version>-->
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <!--<type>pom</type>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any tips?

Comment: Which versions of Spring, Hibernate and EhCache?

Comment: added excerpt from pom.xml to show the versions of all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem went away by adding the below to ehcache.xml. Strange, because I copied and pasted my ehcache.xml from the ehcache web site's getting started section. And, it didn't have that section:

```
<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        />
```

Comment: Weird. On my pet project (without Spring), EHCache complained about my ehcache.xml not having a defaultCache but it didn't fail with a NPE. And it shouldn't. Would be nice if you could create a Jira issue.

Comment: I just ran into the same situation.. setting up ehcache in hibernate for the first time, used the sample ehcache.xml from the website, and got NullPointerExceptions instantiating the session.  Putting in the <defaultCache> element in ehcache.xml fixed it.  Did you open a Jira about this issue?

Comment: By the way, I just found http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration where they show the contents of ehcache-failsafe.xml, containing a minimal config of diskStore and defaultCache.  I guess one should include something like them in any ehcache.xml one provides to ones own application.